# Error occuring on Docker Compose with MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

```
> docker run --name localdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='' -d mysql
```

with the above command, which is working fine, but when doing with docker-compose following error occurs, have seen several questions out there on slack and have google, tried differently but nothing works so far same error.
any proper fix for this issue?

 - Windows 10 

- Docker 18.09.2

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  my-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --disable-partition-engine-check
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password   
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'abc' # ''
       MYSQL_DATABASE: localdb 
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql/data
volumes:
  db_data:
```

[image]

Comment: have your tried setting `- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="true"` ?

Comment: tried all MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'true',   MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1,  MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'

Comment: try assigning a value to `MYSQL_PASSWORD`

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL I tried with all those steps.

Comment: try pulling mysql:5.7 instead of the latest version. they've changed the authentication method in mysql8 (the current version)

Comment: @Efrat I think none of you see for sure details of my question. I did try with 5.7, 8.0 both.

Comment: is there any docker /docker-compose experience person could help??

Comment: sorry @smkrn110 ive read your question again. i dont have asolution but let me state that mysql docker image is meant to work on linux platforms only, as stated in the official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html

Comment:  hmm, well the issue I was facing with docker-compose but not with the first command.